# CSS Mozilla center alignment

Tags: css

I have a page, which after rendering should return cloud tags. And it all works fine. But the alignment of the tags is not in the center in Mozilla. The tags are in the center in chrome and I7, but in Mozilla its just on the left side.

My .html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %} Tag Cloud {% endblock %}
{% block head %} Tag Cloud {% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <div id="tag-cloud">
        {% for tag in tags %}
            <a href="/tag/{{tag.name|urlencode}}/" class="tag-cloud-{{tag.weight}}">{{ tag.name|escape }}</a>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

My .css:

```
#nav {
    float:right;
}

input {
    display:block;
}

ul.tags, ul.tags li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: blue;
    display: inline;
}

#tag-cloud {
    text-align:center;
}

#tag-cloud a {
    margin: 0 0.2em;
}

.tag-cloud-0 { font-sie:100; }
.tag-cloud-1 { font-sie:120; }
.tag-cloud-2 { font-sie:140; }
.tag-cloud-3 { font-sie:160; }
.tag-cloud-4 { font-sie:180; }
.tag-cloud-5 { font-sie:200; }
```

Comment: Try adding `display: block` to `#tag-cloud`

Comment: Sorry, that didn't helped! Any other ideas please.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle?